# Apache Camel : extract to-queue name from message body

Tags: java, apache-camel, quarkus

I have a requirement where I have to send message to Microsoft Teams.
I am trying to extract "to" channel name information from message I receive from queue and based on the channel name, I read it's url from properties file and send message. Below is the code for that.

```
    RouteDefinition from = from("jms:queue:teamsq?connectionFactory=artemis");
    from.setHeader("Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE", constant("application/json"));
    final StringBuffer channelName = new StringBuffer();
    from.process(exchange -> {
        String[] dataArray = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class).split(",", 2);
        channelName.append(dataArray[0]);
        exchange.getIn().setBody("{\"text\" : \"" + dataArray[1].trim() + "\"}");
    })
    .log("Body is : " + channelName + " : ${body}");
```

When body is logged, value of channelName is null.

Any help how can I get value of channelName outside this process() method?

Message received from queue is

```
channel1, This is test a message 5
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set **a message header or an Exchange property**. Both are kind of message variables to use during route processing.

```
.setHeader("channelName", channelName.toString())
.setProperty("channelName", channelName.toString())
```

The main difference is that Exchange properties are sitting on the Camel Exchange while message headers are part of the message itself.

The **Camel Exchange is a Camel wrapper around the message**. It is created when the message enters the route and thrown away at the end of the route.

Exchange Properties:

- are **only available during Camel route processing**
- are **never sent to other systems**
- are only in-memory

Message headers:

- are converted to message headers for the target system whenever the route does a routing to another system
- are therefore sent to other systems
- are serialized when sent to another system

If you send a message from a Camel route to a JMS queue and consume it from another route, the Exchange properties are no more available while the message headers are still present.

However, if you route to a **direct endpoint** (Camel in-memory endpoint), the whole Exchange is transferred and **Exchange properties are still available**.

Comment: Thank you. That helped. Although there is no direct way to extract this header like to getHeaer() or something but using choice() and comparison I was able to find a work around